# Tkinter TkMessageBox not closing after click OK

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, xfce

I have created a script in Python which notifies me at a given event.
I am using the following function to produce the warning window:

```
def window_warn():
    '''
    This function will throw up a window with some text
    '''
    #These two lines get rid of tk root window
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    #tkMessageBox.deiconify() 
    TkMessageBox.showwarning("New Case", "You have a new case\n Please restart pycheck")
    return
```

The window draws fine, but when I click ok, the window stays in place with the button depressed. Im using xfce.
Is there anyway to get the window to close after ok is clicked?

A comment indicated this may be to do with surrounding code, so for completeness:

```
print "Just started newcase check"
while True:
    if "Uncommitted" in webpage:
        print "oh look, 'Uncommitted' is in the url returned from the last function"
        #If this hits we call a notification window
        window_warn()
        print "sleeping"
        time.sleep(10)

        webpage = scrape_page()
    else:
        print "nothing"
        time.sleep(20)
        webpage = scrape_page()
```

Comment: I just added the code which is calling the function for context

Comment: Also, when I run this in the interactive shell it works fine. Not sure if it is because I am not capturing the return `ok`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try calling `root.update()` before returning from the function.  That will process all pending Tk/X window events.

(ideally, you'd establish a main event loop before displaying the window, but that assumes that your entire program is event driven, which may not always work.)

Comment: Thanks,This seems to be exactly it!

Comment: Sorry, would you mid explaining what you mean by main event loop? The program scans a web page every minute.

Comment: Tkinter programs usually (but not always) consist of Tk "on the top" and your code being run by callbacks -- i.e. you set up the Tk part first, call mainloop, and then wait for Tk to call you, usually in response to the user interacting with the program.  That's probably a bit impractical for your case, though.

Comment: Ahh yea. That makes wayyy more sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `root.mainloop()` to enable the program to respond to events.

Comment: So I called `root.mainloop()` right after `tkmb.showwarning("New Case", "You have a new case")` and it seems to just hang, does not do anything. Does it need to be called in a certain way? Thanks

Comment: It has to be running _before_ you open the dialog, since opening the dialog blocks until the dialog is dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

One problem on your code is that you create a new Tk element each time you call the function `window_warn`. This might not be the cause of your issue, but creating multiple Tk elements is a bad practise that should be avoided. For instance, initialize the root element at the beginning and leave only the call to `showwarning`:

```
root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()

def window_warn():
    '''This function will throw up a window with some text'''
    tkMessageBox.showwarning("New Case", "You have a new case\n Please restart pycheck")
    return

print "Just started newcase check"
while True:
    # ...
```

Comment: I see your point here. If I call the root outside the function I can't runt the root.update() on it within the function. Perhaps I have it set up in the incorrect way, and I should have a first run section to initially kick off the root = Tkinter.Tk(), Im running within a terminal box for now anyway so it seems to work fine at the moment (no duplication of windows)

Comment: The code in the function can still access root if it's defined inside the same module (this is called a "global" variable in Python, even though it's only directly visible to code inside the same module).  I don't see any big harm in recreating the Tk root window, though.

Answer (score 0):

I did it tis way:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkMessageBox
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
t = tkMessageBox.askyesno ('Title','Are you sure?')
if t:
    print("Great!!!")
    root.update()
else:
    print("Why?")
    root.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to track if the `tk.messagebox` has occurred, and if it has just break/continue/pass to skip over the re-occurring `tk.messagebox`:

```
Flag = False
if Flag: 
    messagebox.showerror("Error", "Your massage here.")
    Flag = True
else:
    break
```

I propose this because I had issues with other solutions proposed on StackOverflow as I don't have a dedicated `root.mainloop()` but only have `self.mainloop()` within the class `Root()`

My root looks like this and the massage event is generated within some of the inner classes, where I have no access to self.root:

```
    class Root(tk.Tk):
        def __init__(self):
            tk.Tk.__init__(self)
            ....
            class 1..
            class 2..
            self.mainloop()
```